# Openssl encrypted in PHP needs to be decrypted in Ruby

Tags: php, ruby, encryption, openssl, cryptography

In our application we are getting encrypted text from external server. This text have been encrypted using `openssl` in php.

When I am trying to decrypt the text in my Ruby code, I am getting following error message:

```
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: wrong final block length
```

I read couple of solutions on Stackoverflow and was suggest to add following line to the code `cipher.padding = 0`. But after adding `padding = 0`, I am getting different error:

```
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: data not multiple of block length
```

Below is my rough script I have written to decrypt the code.

```
require 'openssl'
require 'digest/sha1'
require 'base64'

encrypted = "VaZYJzn9QVEQIH4fmtA1Cg=="
key = "my_secret_key"

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-128-ecb")

cipher.decrypt
cipher.padding = 0

cipher.key = key

decrypted = cipher.update(encrypted)
decrypted << cipher.final
puts Base64.decode64(decrypted)
```

If I encrypt the text using `Ruby` then I can easily decrypt it. I am having problem to decrypt the code which are encrypted in `php`. Is there any way I can make encryption and decryption compatible between php and Ruby.

Comment: Are you sure that the PHP ciphertext was generated with the same parameters as you're using? i.e. AES with 128-bit block length in ECB mode?

Comment: I don't know ruby at all, but it looks to me like you are base64 decoding after you decrypt instead of before.

Comment: @helmbert yes I am pretty sure that php code is using 128 bit block length in ECB mode.

Comment: @Mike moving base64 decoding before did not make any difference.

Comment: @Reboot [This](https://gist.github.com/tarcieri/5550786) seems to indicate that ECB mode is broken in Ruby OpenSSL. Have you tried using other modes?

Comment: @Mike I don't think that ECB mode is broken because I am able to encrypt and decrypt using Ruby. Problem occurs when encryption is done in php.

Comment: You definitely need to base 64 decode before decrypting. This would explain the errors you see – the encrypted data needs to be multiple of 16 bytes long, base 64 encoding will change the length. Can you provide an actual example that we can try out? What you have looks ok (except for the base 64 thing and the key not being real).

Comment: Hi @matt, putting base64 decode before decrypting fix all the errors. But my output is not in readable format. How can I get the output in more readable form so that I can check if I am getting proper result or not. Currently my output look like this `A�`

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the way you call it.

From `decrypted << cipher.final` to `decrypted = cipher.update(encrypted) + cipher.final`

could get the string like

`<GF\x8F\xDC\x91\xE1ew\xB1\x1C\xE8\xF8V\xA0\x99g\x01C\xCDF\xD6\v\x841l\x13\xA6\x9496{`

Last, quote from Ruby Doc **You should never use ECB mode unless you are absolutely sure that you absolutely need it**